# two identical records don't react the same way

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

[image]

I have a data as shown in picture. When I fetch the records I have different behavior for records
 for record Id=53 when i have

```
myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("ExpirationByDate"))
```

it sends back true  but for 2 rest it sends back false. I don't know how to check the problem

any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`GetOrdinal` returns the column index for the given column name and nothing else. Thus your code do not make sense.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> GetOrdinal performs a case-sensitive lookup first. If it fails, a
>   second, case-insensitive search occurs (a case-insensitive comparison
>   is done using the database collation). Unexpected results can occur
>   when comparisons are affected by culture-specific casing rules. For
>   example, in Turkish, the following example yields the wrong results
>   because the file system in Turkish does not use linguistic casing
>   rules for the letter 'i' in "file". The method throws an
>   IndexOutOfRange exception if the zero-based column ordinal is not
>   found

Did you want to do `reader.IsDBNull(myReader["ExpirationByDate"])`?

I would do:

```
var value = myReader["ExpirationByDate"];
var myBool = value is DbNull ? DefaultSetting : (bool)value;
```

imho it's easier to read.